# TPT script for exporting a large dataset in multiple files

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to get working a tpt script in order to export a large volume of line (15M) into multiple txt files with pipe separator.

Here is my script :

```
DEFINE JOB MYJOB
DESCRIPTION 'Export rows from a Teradata table to a fixed width flat files'
(
 DEFINE SCHEMA SOURCE_SCHEMA
 (
      Run_ID VARCHAR(25),
      CREATE_TS VARCHAR(25),
      top_typ_vision VARCHAR(1) ,
      accounting_date INTDATE,
      instid VARCHAR(5) , 
      top_tiers_retail VARCHAR(1) ,
      SCOPE_RMPM VARCHAR(1) ,
      INT_LIEN_CD_RA VARCHAR(18) ,
      ENT_COMP_CD VARCHAR(3) ,
      code_gen1 VARCHAR(25) ,
      id_doss_aff VARCHAR(50) ,
      code_gen2 VARCHAR(25) ,
      IMPL_CD VARCHAR(5) ,
      CTRL_XTRACPTA_CDT CHAR(2) ,
      ID_AUX2 VARCHAR(25) ,
      ID_OP_AFF VARCHAR(50) ,
      cd_prd_cpta VARCHAR(25) ,
      lieu_stkph_cd VARCHAR(25) ,
      DOSS_CDT VARCHAR(50) ,
      CPTE_GEST_NO VARCHAR(50) ,
      DET_ANA_RAC VARCHAR(50) ,
      DET_ANA_NO VARCHAR(50) ,
      INDIC_CAT_CPT VARCHAR(50) ,
      VERSION_ID VARCHAR(50) ,
      id_sect_base_resp VARCHAR(25) ,
      doss_gest_no VARCHAR(25) ,
      dev_iso_cd VARCHAR(25) ,
      type_obj_risk VARCHAR(2) ,
      ACCOUNTING_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      ASSET_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      LIABILITIE_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      PNL_COST_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      PNL_REV_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      MT_PROV_LIAB DECIMAL(18,2),
      MT_PROV_ASS DECIMAL(18,2),
      MT_HB_GIV DECIMAL(18,2),
      MT_HB_RECEI DECIMAL(18,2),
      MT_REV_REPO DECIMAL(18,2),
      MT_OFF_IFRS DECIMAL(18,2),
      NOT_USED_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      USED_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      ICNE_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      IMP_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      GUARANTEE_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      AMORTIZED_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      PROVISION_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      CAV_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      DEP_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      OFF_BALANCE_SHEET_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      ORIGINAL_PROTECTION_VALUE_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      PROTECTION_VALUE_AMOUNT DECIMAL(18,2),
      type_enr VARCHAR(25) ,
      incorrect_value VARCHAR(25) ,
      rg_no VARCHAR(25) ,
      don_source_cd VARCHAR(25) ,
      nature_regle VARCHAR(2) ,
      mapping_radar VARCHAR(25) ,
      description_regle VARCHAR(1000) ,
      typologie_regle VARCHAR(1) ,
      cd_systeme VARCHAR(3)
 );
 
 DEFINE OPERATOR SQL_SELECTOR
 TYPE SELECTOR
 SCHEMA SOURCE_SCHEMA
 ATTRIBUTES
 (
  VARCHAR TdpId = '********',
  VARCHAR UserName = '*******',
  VARCHAR UserPassword = '******',
  VARCHAR LogonMech = 'LDAP',
  VARCHAR SelectStmt = 'SELECT * FROM DBNAME.TABLE;',
  VARCHAR ReportModeOn
 );
 DEFINE OPERATOR FILE_WRITER
 TYPE DATACONNECTOR CONSUMER
 SCHEMA *
 ATTRIBUTES
 (
  VARCHAR DirectoryPath = 'C:\Users\c92434\Downloads\',
  VARCHAR FileName = 'EXTRACT.txt',
  VARCHAR Format = 'Text',
  VARCHAR OpenMode = 'Write',
  VARCHAR IndicatorMode = 'N',
  VARCHAR TextDelimiter = '|'
 );
 APPLY TO OPERATOR (FILE_WRITER[10])
 VIA OPERATOR (
 SELECT * FROM OPERATOR (SQL_SELECTOR) ;
);
```

I'm getting that error whith command line tbuid -f myscript.tpt - C :

```
Teradata Parallel Transporter Version 16.20.00.06 64-Bit
The global configuration file 'c:\program files\teradata\client\16.20\Teradata Parallel Transporter\twbcfg.ini' is used.
Log Directory: C:\Program Files\Teradata\client\16.20\Teradata Parallel Transporter/logs
Checkpoint Directory: C:\Program Files\Teradata\client\16.20\Teradata Parallel Transporter/checkpoint

TPT_INFRA: Semantic error at or near line 93 of Job Script File 'test.tpt':
TPT_INFRA: TPT03154: Operator 'FILE_WRITER' is not of type 'Standalone'.
Operator is rejected as a target of APPLY operation.
Compilation failed due to errors. Execution Plan was not generated.
Job script compilation failed.

Job terminated with status 8.
```

Why do i get this error and how to remedy ?

Question 2 : How to split by file size ?

Best regards,

Jouvzer

Comment: The error is due to misuse of `VIA` - remove that line. TPT does not currently have an option to split by size. BTW - Format should be `Delimited` not `Text`. And you don't really need to go to the trouble of defining a schema in this case - TPT can infer that from query metadata.

Comment: Can you post the rewrited TPT script please, i've tried to remove VIA but i have still the same error. Best regards, Jouvzer

Comment: The `APPLY` clause is just `APPLY TO OPERATOR (FILE_WRITER[10]) SELECT * FROM OPERATOR (SQL_SELECTOR);`. Also `DirectoryPath` attribute is only valid for a DATACONNECTOR PRODUCER. For CONSUMER, place the full path to the file in `FileName` (and note that when you have multiple instances a hyphen and the operator sequence number will be appended).